# Should I add vapor barrier between lath and drywall if only on half the wall?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, old-house, vapor-barrier, lath-and-plaster

I’m renovating a bathroom in my 125 year old home in Northern Michigan. The bathroom has lath and plaster walls with old wood panel wainscoting on the bottom 1/3rd of the walls. The plaster above the paneling is in rough shape so I’m planning to remove the plaster, add vapor barrier, then drywall over it. However, I’m hoping to keep the paneling (and the plaster under it) intact. Two walls are exterior with cellulose insulation behind the lath.

Are there any obvious issues with adding the plastic vapor barrier just on the top half of the wall – or is it even necessary since it won’t be fully sealed?

Comment: In my experience it's much easier to remove the plaster and lath _together_, then fur out the framing for 5/8" drywall (to better match the robust nature of the plaster). It's less putzy and leaves you with a flatter surface.

Comment: Why are you putting a vapor barrier on the inside of the wall to begin with? Does your house have air conditioning, or an exterior vapor barrier for that matter?

Comment: We don’t want to remove the lath because it’s holding the cellulose insulation up and we don’t want to deal with redoing all of that. I had originally planned to fix the plaster or drywall directly over it but it’s in too bad of shape and all the trim etc would require much more furring out to line up. Remove plaster, keep lath was best compromise. 

I wasn’t sure on the vapor barrier and had only recently started thinking I’d add it after some other research. It does have air conditioning, and as far as I’ve found no exterior barrier. (New to us house)

Comment: Also, my reasoning for considering adding the poly was based on this Fine Home Building  piece which I know is for modern building (hence why I wasn’t sure and asked here). https://www.finehomebuilding.com/pdf/021151052.pdf

Thanks for the helpful replies!

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter of opinion. Mine is that vapor barrier generally shouldn't be added to such old homes unless as part of a full insulation/siding/ventilation upgrade renovation. You  probably don't accomplish anything putting up a postage stamp of plastic, and you could end up creating a mold factory.

Comment: I struggle with this as well but I am not sure it matters either way.  If you put the poly in, have you really reduced the interior drying potential if the previous material was lath/plaster with an oil ( vapor barrier ) paint.  If you are doing the whole thing, taping all seams, using acoustic seal then you probably want to make sure you actually have rainscreen on the exterior and the wall assembly can dry to the outside.

Comment: This was my original thought too but recently started thinking adding vapor barrier would be beneficial, but maybe that’s not the case. It’s hard to know what modern advice is or isn’t best for these old houses. 
As far as I’ve found it’s just the old wood siding and no rehabs with house wrap or rainscreen have been done. (All still in great shape though so it must breath ok even with the added AC).